# Red5 application redeploy without deleting deployed application folder

Tags: deployment, war, red5, redeploy

Only way i know to deploy new war to Red5 server is to stop the server, delete deployed application folder from webapps folder, copy application war into webapps folder and start the server again. Is there a way to speed up the process, preferably just copy war into webapps folder without deleting the deployed application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a .war is nothing else then a zipped version of your webapp.
So if you know which files have changed you can simply only replace those.

If your changes only affect .html or .swf files or only images then you will not even need to restart.
However any jar file, change to web.xml or other servlet container specific files will need a restart of the servlet container (no matter if you are using Tomcat or Jetty).

Sebastian